# sqlalchemy order_by_clause inspection

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy expression statment that I'm rendering to a HTML table. The thing is that I write a bit of extra code, to show which columns are being filtered and ordered by. Is there a simple way to inspect the select object, in for example descending or ascending order?

```
select(
[rt.id, rt.nbr, rt.dbnbr, rt.name
,functions.concat(dt.nbr, ' ', dt.name).label('depname')])
.where(rt.depid == dt.id).where(r.name.ilike('%vård%'))
.order_by(rt.name.desc(), rt.nbr 
,functions.concat(dt.nbr, ' ', dt.name).label('depname'))
.limit(5).offset(2)
```

[image: html table]